# Supabase Flutter fetching multiple UUIDs

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-database

How can I optimize my SQL query and data retrieval process for displaying a user's followers from three tables: 'users' (contains user metadata), 'followers' (contains an array of UUIDs for all followers), and 'following' (contains an array of UUIDs for all following users)? Currently, I'm retrieving all the UUIDs and then fetching the profile metadata for each UUID from the 'users' table. I attempted to create an array of foreign keys in Supabase but encountered issues. The current code is working fine but is there a more efficient query or pagination method to fetch and display follower data? I'm new to SQL, having migrated from Firebase. Thank you for your assistance.

Query Code:

```
  /// Stores all the UUID from the circle
  List totalFollowers = [];

  /// Fn to fetch all the users in the circle
  Future<void> fetchFollowersDB() async {
    try {
      final data = await supabase
          .from('followers')
          .select('followers_list')
          .eq(
            'user_id',
            _currentUuid,
          )
          .single();

      // Update profileModel with the retrieved data
      if (data != null) {
        totalFollowers = data['followers_list'];
      } else {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Error fetching profile data: ${data.error?.message}');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
    }

    update();
  }

  /// Stores all the Profile data for the circle
  List<ProfileModel> followersProfiles = [];

  /// Get Profile data as per UUID
  Future<void> fetchFollowersProfiles() async {
    followersProfiles.clear();

    //
    for (var uuid in totalFollowers) {
      try {
        final data = await supabase
            .from('users')
            .select('*')
            .eq(
              'uuid',
              uuid,
            )
            .single();

        // Add profileModel to circleProfiles
        if (data != null) {
          followersProfiles.add(ProfileModel.fromMap(data));
        } else {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('Error fetching profile data: ${data.error?.message}');
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
    }

    update();
  }
```

Widget

```
class FollowersAndFollowingTab extends StatelessWidget {
  List usersList;

  FollowersAndFollowingTab({super.key, required this.usersList});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<DBController>(
      builder: (_) => ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: usersList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          ProfileModel userProfile = usersList[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      fullscreenDialog: true,
                      builder: (context) => ProfileViewScreen(
                        profileModel: userProfile,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                leading: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image:
                          CachedNetworkImageProvider(userProfile.profilePhoto!),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  '${_bioWidgets.fullNameNoFlag(
                    profileModel: userProfile,
                  )} ${_bioWidgets.returnFlagEmoji(
                    profileModel: userProfile,
                  )}',
                ),
                subtitle: Text('@${userProfile.username!}'),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.more_vert,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, imo storing those values as arrays defeats the purpose of relational data! But I can understand, considering you're coming from FireBase.

## Data modelling

### Your current approach

[image]

### Better approach

[image]

## Fetching data

### Approach 1 - Queries with FK

Why do it with your code if you can get SQL to do it instead? ;)
Go to Supabase -> Table Editor -> your table -> API and check this part:
[image]
It's possible to fetch the FK table as well when querying. Although you need to put in some trial and error to get it to work considering you have multiple FKs pointing to the same table. Anyway, would look something like this:

```
final data = await supabase
   .from('followers')
   .select(`uuid, follower_uuid,
      users (
         uuid,
         name
      )`
    )
   .eq('uuid', _currentUuid)
```

If you want it as an array, there's an SQL function `array` to do it. If not, handle it in your application code.
This is my recommended approach.

### Approach 2 - Views

If you find yourself querying a bunch of tables all the time in the future, you can create a "view" - basically a group of data that you need from multiple tables. You can then query the view via an API call like you would a table.
This is an example, just so you know what's possible.

Example code to create a view:

```sql
create or replace view
  public.followers_with_names WITH (security_invoker = true) as
select distinct
  users.uuid,
  users.name,
  (
    select
      array (
        select
          users2.name
        from
          users users2
        where
          users2.uuid = followers.uuid
      ) as follower_names
  ) as follower_names
from
  users
  join followers on users.uuid = followers.uuid;
```

After that if you just call `followers_with_names` like a normal table, you'll get `uuid`, `name` and an array of follower names. Like

```
final data = await supabase
          .from('followers_with_names')
          .select('*')
          .eq(
            'user_id',
            _currentUuid,
          )
```

---

Anyway, I'd love to chat if you have more queries. Leave your email on your profile page if you want to, I'll contact you :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, and I have a few questions. It's clear that you're proficient in SQL, and I find your approach quite appealing. However, it would be even more beneficial if you could provide details about the actual tables and include some Flutter code examples. Nevertheless, as a SQL novice, I'm genuinely enjoying the learning process—it's like a captivating game of connecting the dots. I currently have three production apps that rely on Firebase as the main database, but I'm considering migrating to Supabase for its SQL capabilities in the future. Here are my questions: @Bojan Krkic

Comment: Questions: - In my current approach, is there a possibility of encountering invalid UUIDs when the UUIDs are inserted via authentication?
- Regarding your approach, what happens if a user accumulates millions of followers? Could this potentially create performance issues or put a strain on the tables, considering that Firebase has a document limit of 1 MB?
- How can I create views in Supabase to simplify data access? @Bojan Krkic

Comment: Additionally, for a community network application, is it advisable to have separate tables for distinct purposes such as 'users,' 'followers,' 'premium_followers,' 'post_text,' 'post_audio,' 'post_image,' 'likes,' and so on? I've watched numerous tutorials, but I'm keen to know what experts recommend.

Feel free to reach out to me via email at rajaaravsahi@gmail.com. Your expertise and guidance are highly appreciated. Thank you! @Bojan Krkic

Comment: "is there a possibility of encountering invalid UUIDs when the UUIDs are inserted via authentication" yes, only the "uuid" column is inserted via auth (ie, the uuid of the current user) - we can assume that's always right. However the "follower_uuid" might not always be right considering it's inserted from the app; and it safe to assume there are chances of errors in the app.

Comment: "what happens if a user accumulates millions of followers? Could this potentially create performance issues or put a strain on the tables" no, you should be good. Postgres can deal with millions of entries. The main bottleneck then becomes joins in your queries, to which I would suggest views. Or even sharding at a later stage, although you'd have to look that part up wrt Supabase. But take that when it comes, you don't need to think about it have. If you really start having that problem, it means you've succeeded with your app and potentially have the $ to being expert suggestions.

Comment: " is it advisable to have separate tables for distinct purposes such as 'users,' 'followers,' 'premium_followers,' 'post_text,' 'post_audio,' 'post_image,' 'likes,'" some yes, some no. followers - yes, premium_followers should just be an extra column on followers, not a separate table. You will definitely have more use cases in the future, it's better to keep them as columns.